# Manipulating with array adapter or with the underlaying data?

Tags: android

In the book *The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development* from CommonsWare, there is a chapter explaining how to work with the context menus.

In one example in that chapter, the context menu offers option for removing item from a list view that is generated from an `ArrayList<String>` object named `words`.

In the example the `onContextItemSelected` method is implemented like this:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {   
  case R.id.remove:
    adapter.remove(words.get(info.position));
    return true;
  default:
  ...
}
```

The line where `adapter.remove(...)` is called seems strange to me because of following fact:

Let's say the `words` object contains following items (in that order)

- alfa
- beta
- gama
- alfa

Now, when user loads the context menu upon the *2nd* alfa and selects the option for removing it, the mentioned line actually removes the *1st* alfa. And that seems wrong to me.

Instead, I would do something like this:

```
...
words.remove(info.position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

I'm not that good in Java and Android programming, so I would like to hear your opinion to this, because I want to be sure I understand well how adapters should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea sounds good.

The example is defunct if it behaves like you have described and you should tell Mark about it so he can check it as well (he'll probably do it anyway since he is very active on this site).